# Issue with Chinese characters, PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, sql, cjk

I have a MySQL database with the following settings:
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
MySQL connection collation: utf8_unicode_ci

I have a table with a column named "softtitle", this column is coded in utf8_general_ci. The entries of this column contain Chinese characters. If I run SQL through the PHPMyAdmin Control pane, the Chinese characters are shown correctly. But if I run SQL through a PHP file, all Chinese characters are shown wrongly. Here is the PHP file:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8_general_ci"); 

mysql_connect("116.123.163.73","xxdd_f1","xxdd123"); // host, username, password
mysql_select_db("xxdd");

mysql_query("SET names 'utf8_general_ci'"); 

$q = mysql_query("SELECT  softtitle
FROM  dede_ext
LIMIT 0 , 30");

while($e = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[] = $e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

What is wrong here? What should I do to fix this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: shouln'd it be `header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` instead of `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8_general_ci");`

Answer (score 4):

You header is wrong. You're not supposed to set it to the character set of the table/database.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

The same applies for "SET NAMES":

```
mysql_query("SET names 'utf8'");
```

And as a last thing, you are printing out json encoded data, your `Content-type` shouldn't be `text/html` but `application/json`.

Comment: After i have changed the code like you said. Nothing displays on the webseit. What's wrong? Thank you!

Comment: How could I, or anyone know that? Have a look at your error messages (logs?).

Comment: Sorry, the problem caused by a missing '/' character before the comment :-)

Comment: But still, the problem of showing chinese characters is not solved. Instead of showing "Test中文"，the webseit shows me "Test\u4e2d\u6587". How can i make it display correctly?

Answer (score 0):

because this Q&A still ranks highly in Google search results..

setting aside for a moment the general advice to switch from using mysql statements in php to using mysqli, replace this:

```
mysql_connect("116.123.163.73","xxdd_f1","xxdd123");
mysql_select_db("xxdd");
```

with this:

```
$con = mysql_connect("116.123.163.73","xxdd_f1","xxdd123");
mysql_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
mysql_select_db("xxdd");
```

check that your database, or at least the column,  really IS collated as utf8_general_ci - though you might get better results with utf8mb4_unicode_ci

if your php is producing a purely JSON output, for example, a JSON 'object' that you're picking up with an AJAX call to pull data into another document, the header you should use in the PHP file is
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

and not a header content-type of text/html or anything else.

and finally, assuming you're eventually presenting the values taken from the DB and placed into your JSON onto an html document, remember the to start that document with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-Hans">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
...etc
```

note the declaration of utf-8 in the meta of the head, and the declaration of the language (chinese simplified in my code above = zh-Hans). If you are using a script which is written from right to left, eg. arabic sccripts, add dir="rtl" into the  tag as well.